# Application crashing when activate meteor(turkserver)

Tags: javascript, meteor, amazon-iam

I followed the tutorial in [this](http://turkserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/tutorial.html#getting-started), and failed at this step. 
After edited the meteor by `--settings settings.json`,there is a problem occurred

```
    HelixG-2:app apple$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/app ]]]]]                             

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.       



W20171215-11:26:04.271(8)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20171215-11:26:04.300(8)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20171215-11:26:04.301(8)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20171215-11:26:04.301(8)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20171215-11:26:04.301(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:04.301(8)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20171215-11:26:04.302(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:04.302(8)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
I20171215-11:26:04.510(8)? Missing Amazon API keys for connecting to MTurk. Please configure.
W20171215-11:26:04.526(8)? (STDERR) /Users/apple/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.194csmy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20171215-11:26:04.527(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20171215-11:26:04.527(8)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20171215-11:26:04.527(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:04.528(8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Template is not defined
W20171215-11:26:04.528(8)? (STDERR)     at demo.js (demo.js:1:1)
W20171215-11:26:04.528(8)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20171215-11:26:04.529(8)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20171215-11:26:04.529(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:57:1
W20171215-11:26:04.529(8)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info (/Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:414:13)
W20171215-11:26:04.529(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20171215-11:26:04.530(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:413:9
W20171215-11:26:04.530(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:5
W20171215-11:26:04.530(8)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20171215-11:26:04.530(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:462:11
=> Exited with code: 1
W20171215-11:26:05.734(8)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20171215-11:26:05.735(8)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20171215-11:26:05.735(8)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20171215-11:26:05.735(8)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20171215-11:26:05.736(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:05.736(8)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20171215-11:26:05.736(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:05.736(8)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
I20171215-11:26:05.965(8)? Missing Amazon API keys for connecting to MTurk. Please configure.
W20171215-11:26:05.981(8)? (STDERR) /Users/apple/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.194csmy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20171215-11:26:05.981(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20171215-11:26:05.981(8)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20171215-11:26:05.982(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:05.982(8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Template is not defined
W20171215-11:26:05.982(8)? (STDERR)     at demo.js (demo.js:1:1)
W20171215-11:26:05.982(8)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20171215-11:26:05.983(8)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20171215-11:26:05.983(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:57:1
W20171215-11:26:05.983(8)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info (/Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:414:13)
W20171215-11:26:05.984(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20171215-11:26:05.984(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:413:9
W20171215-11:26:05.984(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:5
W20171215-11:26:05.984(8)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20171215-11:26:05.985(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:462:11
=> Exited with code: 1
W20171215-11:26:07.101(8)? (STDERR) Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
W20171215-11:26:07.102(8)? (STDERR) While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
W20171215-11:26:07.102(8)? (STDERR) approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
W20171215-11:26:07.102(8)? (STDERR) In order to use the native implementation instead, run
W20171215-11:26:07.103(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:07.103(8)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save bcrypt
W20171215-11:26:07.103(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:07.104(8)? (STDERR) in the root directory of your application.
I20171215-11:26:07.344(8)? Missing Amazon API keys for connecting to MTurk. Please configure.
W20171215-11:26:07.359(8)? (STDERR) /Users/apple/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.194csmy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20171215-11:26:07.360(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20171215-11:26:07.360(8)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20171215-11:26:07.360(8)? (STDERR) 
W20171215-11:26:07.360(8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Template is not defined
W20171215-11:26:07.360(8)? (STDERR)     at demo.js (demo.js:1:1)
W20171215-11:26:07.361(8)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20171215-11:26:07.361(8)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20171215-11:26:07.361(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:57:1
W20171215-11:26:07.361(8)? (STDERR)     at infos.forEach.info (/Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:414:13)
W20171215-11:26:07.362(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20171215-11:26:07.362(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:413:9
W20171215-11:26:07.362(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:5
W20171215-11:26:07.362(8)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20171215-11:26:07.362(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:462:11
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

And the http://localhost:3000/turkserver look like this :

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log:
Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt.
While this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
approximately three times slower than the native implementation.
In order to use the native implementation instead, run

  meteor npm install --save bcrypt

in the root directory of your application.
Missing Amazon API keys for connecting to MTurk. Please configure.
/Users/apple/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.0_1.194csmy++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
                        throw(ex);
                        ^

ReferenceError: Template is not defined
    at demo.js (demo.js:1:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
    at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:57:1
    at infos.forEach.info (/Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:414:13)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:413:9
    at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:463:5
    at Function.run (/Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
    at /Users/apple/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:462:11
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

There seems to be a problem with the  Amazon API keys. But I don't know whats wrong.
Is this the account problem? Or something wrong with the packages/environment

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your app with `meteor --settings settings.json` that's why it's saying `Missing Amazon API keys for connecting to MTurk. Please configure.`.

The `Template is not defined` error is caused by front-end code on the server side.
I'm pretty sure you did a `meteor update` after you cloned the tutorial repo and this was your mistake.
**Don't update it!**
The new meteor version handles the project structure differently.